# Django Rest Framework: changing output format of annotated field in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am currently struggling with specifying an output format in my views.py. I have a column "date" which is using following format: *2021-01-14*.
In my response, I would like to change the date format so that it only shows the year *2021*.

I already tried it with *Cast* but it seems like this is not the right approach.
For this view, I do not use a Serializer, hence adding it there would not be an option.

**views.py**

```
class FilterParams(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Variants
    queryset = Variants.objects.all()
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        ModelsByYears = queryset.values('model').distinct().annotate(min_year=Min('date')).annotate(max_year=Max('date')).order_by('model')
        return Response(data= {'ModelsByYears':ModelsByYears})
```

**What I tried:**

```
class FilterParams(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Variants
    queryset = Variants.objects.all()
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        ModelsByYears = queryset.values('model').distinct().annotate(min_year=Min(Cast('date', DateTimeField(format="%Y")))).annotate(max_year=Max('date')).order_by('model')
        return Response(data= {'ModelsByYears':ModelsByYears})
```

**Error message**

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Extract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#extract)/[`ExtractYear`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractYear) database function instead

> Takes an expression representing a DateField, DateTimeField,
> TimeField, or DurationField and a lookup_name, and returns the part of
> the date referenced by lookup_name as an IntegerField. Django usually
> uses the databases’ extract function, so you may use any lookup_name
> that your database supports.

Comment: Works great with Extract. Thank you very much for your help :)